# Printing several PDF files via Angular2

Tags: angular

To receive PDF files from server and print it via Angular2 in browser I use code as below:

```
this.http.get(url, {
  headers: headers,
  responseType: 'blob'
  }).subscribe(
    (resp) => {
      let pdf = new Blob([resp], { type: 'application/pdf' });
      let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(pdf);
      let frm = document.createElement('iframe');
      frm.style.display = 'none';
      frm.src = objectURL;
      document.body.appendChild(frm);
      frm.contentWindow.print();
});
```

But it works perfect only when I receive and print out just one or two PDF files.

In case I sent to server for more then two requests (in loop) and then wait for print windows to print it in queue, some print windows opens as blank pages with some empty code in it:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body></body>
</html>
```

If I generate buttons and put them near each iframe to print it out separately one by one it works good, but if try to print it in queue I receive some blank pages.

Why I may have such behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

with your solution I wasn't able to print just a single document. I guess the print command was fired to early. I was able to fix it with waiting for the loading of the frame being finished:

```
this.http.get(urls[0], {
    responseType: 'blob'
  }).subscribe(
      (resp) => {
          let pdf = new Blob([resp], { type: 'application/pdf' });
          let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(pdf);
          let frm = document.createElement('iframe');
          frm.style.display = 'none';
          frm.src = objectURL;
          document.body.appendChild(frm);
          frm.onload = function () {
              console.log('Page was loaded');
              frm.contentWindow.print();
          }
});
```